# Свиток на css и html

Tags: css, css3, стилизация

[image: Свиток]

Как с помощью css и html создать такое? При чем я уверен что такой вопрос уже задавался и ответ есть, как минимум в гугле. Найти не могу. Буду признателен за любую помощь. Картинками делать не хочу, а знаний не хватает

Comment: Можно использовать SVG (векторная графика), Canvas (растровая)

Comment: а если не хотите изображением и не умеете может быть на фриланс обратится ?

Comment: Тут дело не во фрилансе. Хотелось бы самому попробовать или почитать что-либо. 100% нечто подобное уже есть, но найти не могу

Comment: @Дмитрий я открою вам тайну - на чистом html css это ни сделать , тут по баще нужна технология : svg

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Не правда! Я сделал.

Comment: Нижнюю и верхнюю части скорее всего придётся через svg делать. CSSом конечно возможно имитировать все эти скругления, но очень геморно, долго и не удобно.

Answer (score 1):

А чего сложного то?

```css
.scroll {
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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);
    width: 160px;
    height: 180px;
    background-size: 250px 250px;
    padding: 20px 50px 50px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  text text text
</div>
```

base64.

Comment: так сам свиток картинкой в base64 - это не решение